# IMacros: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript, imacros

I have a problem when I change the code from IIM to JS I face this message "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement, line 5 (Error code: -991)"

original code is working perfectly

```
SET !DATASOURCE Pack_01.txt
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE 1
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!COL1}}\"; s.split(\"@\")[1];")
PROMPT ID:{{!VAR1}}
```

but the js code is not working for my

```
var macro;
macro = "CODE:"; 
macro += "SET !DATASOURCE Pack_01.txt" + "\n";  
macro += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE 1" + "\n";  
macro += "SET !VAR1 EVAL(\"var s=\\"{{!COL1}}\"; s.split(\"@\")[1];")" + "\n";  
macro += "PROMPT ID:{{!VAR1}}" + "\n";  
iimPlay(macro);
```

can you help, please!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is not correct because your string contains double quotes. You need to escape them, replacing " with \".

```
var macro;
macro = "CODE:";
macro += "SET !DATASOURCE Pack_01.txt" + "\n";
macro += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE 1" + "\n";
macro += "SET !VAR1 EVAL(\"var s=\\\"{{!COL1}}\\\"; s.split(\\\"@\\\")[1];\")" + "\n";
macro += "PROMPT ID:{{!VAR1}}" + "\n";
iimPlay(macro);
```

Another option is to use template literals:

```
var macro = `CODE:SET !DATASOURCE Pack_01.txt
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE 1
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\\"{{!COL1}}\\"; s.split(\\"@\\")[1];")
PROMPT ID:{{!VAR1}}
`;
iimPlay(macro);
```

Comment: doesn't it work just as fine if you use single quotes instead of double quotes around the whole string? I mean, just to improve readability?